# I am unable to getStatusesByTag of the enqueueUniquePeriodicWork through WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using `WorkManager` via `implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"` to start a `PeriodicWorkRequest` to call a Rest API to pull some data at interval `PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` which is 15 minutes, my code is:

```
    PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder builder = new
            PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class,
            PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addTag(TAG_WORKER)
            .setInputData(createInputData(config));
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(TAG_WORKER,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, builder.build());
```

I want to know the status or the `PeriodicWorkRequest` enqueued by `WorkManager` by its TAG, through the code:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag(TAG_WORKER);
```

But I am unable to resolve the method `getStatusesByTag(TAG_WORKER)`, please help if anyone did the workaround to get the Status of Request been enqueued by TAG.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean "enable to resolve"?

Answer (score 0):

The API to get information on the WorkRequest's status changed last year with [1.0.0-alpha11](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#1.0.0-alpha11). To know the status of your work you can use:

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(TAG_WORKER)
    .observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
          if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
              displayMessage("Work finished!")
          }
        }
    });
```

You can find more information on WorkManager's documentation page: ["Work States and observing work"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation#java)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `unique` work. To observe unique work you should be using 
[getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html#getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(java.lang.String)) API.

Edit: Re-read your code snippet and realized that you are also adding a `tag`. You can also use the `getWorkInfosByTagLiveData` API mentioned in the answer below.